# Show information of database in a listbox vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, ms-access, listbox

I want to show information of my database (ACCESS) and show that in a listbox.

I tried to do that with this follow code:

```
Public Sub listbox()

    Dim dt As DataTable

    Using con
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Livrosescola", con)
        Dim oDA As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        dt = New DataTable()
        oDA.Fill(dt)
    End Using

    ListBox1.DataSource = dt
```

Didnt work :/
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to add "ListBox1.DisplayMember = "FieldNameYouWantToShow" and call "listbox()" in

```
Private Sub Livros_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\311026\Documents\PAP3\Biblio.accdb"
    con.Open()

listbox()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the DataBind () method of the ListBox. After data link control in ASP.NET, you always have to call the DataBind () method.

```
 ListBox1.DataBind()
```

More info:
[Control.DataBind Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5e5992d(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It would appear that this is WinForms

Comment: Ok i did it. Like @Crush Sundae said i only needed to display the member and that call the public sub in form load.